# PHPWord addTOC is not displaying page numbers

Tags: phpword, phpoffice

I'm using https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord to generate a word document.
The function addTOC generates an index of pages with titles, but for some reason the page numbers do not display.

```
// add table of contents
$section->addTOC();
```

Results in:

[image: Table of contents]

If I echo the page numbers on the pages where the titles exist, they display fine.  But they don't display in the TOC.  I checked to confirm the text isn't white.

Comment: I figured this out, the author name is troosan, he is on this stackoverflow. Btw check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

From PHPWord example in samples dir (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_17_TitleTOC.php), I would tell it is not possible:

> echo date('H:i:s'), ' Note: Please refresh TOC manually.', EOL;

I also tried to add the TOC at the end of the document, after titles declarations (when we already know page numbers). But with no success.

EDIT: seems to be a bug: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/707