# PHPWord addTOC do not show page numbers

Tags: phpword

When I use Phpword function `addTOC`, it is not displaying the page numbers.

```
// add table of contents
$section->addTOC();
```

Comment: why do you expect page numbers to be shown when you add a table of contents. Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - your question not exactly verbose on what you do and try.

Comment: Duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267654/phpword-addtoc-is-not-displaying-page-numbers/38995552

Answer (score 1):

you need to include the following:

```
$phpWord->getSettings()->setUpdateFields(true);
```

this will prompt the user to update the ToC when they open the file (saving it will then store the page numbers)